# Extend s3 pre-signed url expiry

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, pre-signed-url

I have a lambda that generates the S3 resigned URL and send back the resigned URL. Presigned URLs expire after 12 hours, assuming this is due to the expiry of temporary authenticaton tokens (I have set presign expiry to 7 days). Wondering how I can increase this 12 hours to 24 hours.

This is how Im creating the s3 client in go.

````
    awsSession := session.Must(
        session.NewSessionWithOptions(
            session.Options{
                Config:             aws.Config{Region: aws.String("us-west-2")},
                AssumeRoleDuration: sessionExpiry,
            },
        ),
    )
    return &s3Client{
        client: s3.New(awsSession),
    }```
````

Comment: The max assume role duration is 12 hours, so it's not possible to extend it to 24 hours if you use keys generated from roles to sign the url. An alternative is to use permanent access keys to sign the url.